# Custom layout draws position 0 off screen when content is larger than screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to write a calendar/excel like screen where you can diagonally scroll the content and the column/row headers stay in place.

It's using a custom layout with placeables, where the layout is the whole drawable space, and then the events are drawn within the box where they are needed.

For example

Column 0 starts at X=0 Y=0, and each column is some width.  So column 1 draws at 0, column 2 at 20, column 3 at 40 etc.

It all works correctly until the content size becomes larger than the visible width of the screen, the content that starts at position 0 starts getting drawn off screen, such as at -20.  Almost like it's centering the content...

Here's some pics of whats happening when the size fits and then doesn't fit

[image]
[image]

I think it might have something to do with alignment lines in the custom layout but if it does i can't figure out what it wants me to do... I've tried alignments on the column set to start as well to no avail.

Here's a bare bones example of the problem

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleTest(columnList: List<String>) {
    val headerWidth = 150

    Column {
        HeaderTest(columnList, headerWidth)
    }
}


@Composable
fun HeaderTest(
    columnList: List<String>,
    headerWidth: Int,
    headerContent: @Composable (title: String) -> Unit = { title ->
        Text(title)
    },
) {
    val numberOfHeaders = columnList.count()

    Layout(
        content = {
            columnList.forEach { header ->
                Box {
                    headerContent(header)
                }
            }
        }
    ) { measureables, constraints ->

        val height = 45.dp.roundToPx()
        val totalWidth = headerWidth * numberOfHeaders

        val placeWithHeader = measureables.map { measurable ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(
                constraints.copy(
                    minWidth = headerWidth,
                    maxWidth = headerWidth,
                    minHeight = height,
                    maxHeight = height,
                )
            )

            placeable
        }

        layout(width = totalWidth, height = height) {
            placeWithHeader.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                val offset = index * headerWidth
                placeable.place(offset, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been able to workaround the problem by taking the total screen width and when it's smaller than the total width, dividing by two, and adding that as an additional offset, but this feels like the wrong way to solve the problem, so hoping for a proper solution

Comment: I'm having the same problems on height now, and this workaround isn't working... 0 isn't drawing at 0, and the halfway adjustment doesn't fix it either, its close but not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped with this on another forum but they didn't answer it here.

I wasn't constraining the main layouts width and height

```
val height = 45.dp.roundToPx()
val totalWidth = headerWidth * numberOfHeaders
```

> the contract of layout is that the width/height passed to layout must
> be in range of the constraints, if you violate that, your measurable
> gets clamped to the constraints and your placement is centered in the
> clamped space where your parent placed you

I needed to add constraints to it

```
val height = 45.dp.roundToPx().coerceIn(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)
val totalWidth = headerWidth * numberOfHeaders.coerceIn(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth)
```